# sysdate is not set to current date in oracle dB

Tags: oracle, docker

oracle dB sysdate is off by few days.

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
---------------
10-AUG-20
```

How to update this to current date time? thanks. The dB is hosted in a docker container.

Comment: Is the system clock of the Docker host accurate? Is the system clock inside the Docker container accurate?

Comment: I noticed that system time of docker host is not accurate. correcting that...

Comment: ["`SYSDATE` returns the current date and time set for the operating system on which the database server resides."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYSDATE.html)

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved after restarting docker service. which set the time properly.